# This is a question on series

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$\frac{1}{1+x} + \frac{2x}{1+x^2} + \frac{4x^3}{1+x^4} +\frac{8x^7}{1+x^8} +\cdots$$ up to infinity

Not being able to solve this.

Comment: Use MathJax, lest not many will want to try to read this.

Comment: What are you trying to "solve?"  Are you trying to decide whether it converges or not? or are you trying to figure out what the sum is?  Also, a little mathjax formatting will help a lot to make this more readable.  See: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference for a good guide.

Comment: this converges. I need to find out its value and how to solve it.

Comment: You solve equations, or inequations, Series are not solved, but computed. Also you might want to now only if the series converges. Please specify.

Comment: what is the next term?

Comment: Did you miss a $1+x^3$ term?  The pattern isn't clear here...

Comment: 6x^5/(1+x^6) is the next term

Comment: Do you think the enumerator expressions resemble corresponding denominator expressions' derivative...?

Comment: yes it is. If we take y = (1+x)*(1+x^2)*(1+x^4)*....., then the series is coming out to be (1/y)*y'

Comment: @TravisJ's remark is still fully relevant, I am afraid.

Comment: Every positive integer has a unique representation in base $2$. Can you see how this fact is related to the given question? Expand every term as a geometric series and compute the coefficient of $x^k$.

Answer (score 2):

The series can be written as:
$$
\begin{gathered}
  f(x) = \sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\frac{{d/dx\left( {1 + x^{\,2^{\,k} } } \right)}}
{{1 + x^{\,2^{\,k} } }}}  = \frac{d}
{{dx}}\sum\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\ln \left( {1 + x^{\,2^{\,k} } } \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{d}
{{dx}}\ln \prod\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( {1 + x^{\,2^{\,k} } } \right)}  = \frac{d}
{{dx}}\ln \left( {\frac{1}
{{1 - x}}} \right) = \frac{1}
{{1 - x}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
since
$$
\prod\limits_{0\, \leqslant \,k} {\left( {1 + x^{\,2^{\,k} } } \right)}  = \left( {1 + x + x^{\,2}  + \; \cdots } \right) = \frac{1}
{{1 - x}}
$$

refer to ["Lectures on Integer Partitions"- H. S. Wilf](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/PIMS/PIMSLectures.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

If the 4th term was $\frac{8x^7}{1+x^8}$ rather than $\frac{6x^5}{1+x^6}$ then there is a simple solution:
 $$ \frac{1}{(1-x)} $$

Integrating your series you get:
$$ \ln(1+x) + \ln(1+x^2) + \ln(1+x^4) + \ln(1+x^8) + ... = \ln \prod_{k\geq 0} (1 + x^{2^k})= \ln(\sum_{j\geq 0} x^j) = \ln \frac{1}{1-x}$$
Then take a derivative.

Comment: i guess so. You are right. The 4th term should be such.